# Timing primes generation in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, primes

This will be a question to people really familiar with Clojure.
I wanted to write simple primes checking function in Java and in Clojure, and compare execution times.
So here is my code in Java:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Primes {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    getPrimes(10000);
    long end = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println(((float)(end - start)/1000000) + "ms");
}

private static LinkedList<Integer> getPrimes(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    int current = 1;
    LinkedList<Integer> primes = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    while(count <= n)
    {
        if(isPrime(current))
        {
            primes.add(current);
            count++;
        }
        current++;
    }
    return primes;
}

private static boolean isPrime(long n)
{
    if(n <= 0) return false;
    if(n == 1 || n == 2) return true;
    if(n % 2 == 0) return false;
    for(int i=3; i<Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i=i+2)
    {
        if(n % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

And here is Clojure equivalent:

```
(defn prime? [n]
  (or (= n 2) (not (some #(zero? (rem n %)) (conj (range 3 (inc (Math/sqrt n)) 2) 2)))))

(defn printPrimes [n] (take n (filter prime? (iterate inc 1))))

(defn ExecTime [function & arguments] (let [start (System/nanoTime), return (dorun (apply function arguments)), end (System/nanoTime)] (/ (- end start) 1000000.0)))

(ExecTime printPrimes 10000)
```

Now there are few things I am not sure of:

1. Is (let) and binding start and end time ok way to measure the execution time in Clojure?
2. For some reason (even though Java and Clojure versions use the same algorithm) the Clojure version is much slower (J: ~50ms, C: ~400ms). Am I doing something wrong?

Excuse me my ignorance if I have made some obvious mistake but I am still at the learning stage with Clojure...

-----EDIT-----

I have optimised it and eventually achieved times same as Java. I describe it in my blog for people interested:
http://blog.programmingdan.com/?p=35

Comment: `if(n == 1 || n == 2) return true;` By the commonly used definition(s), 1 is not a prime.

Comment: yep I realized, already fixed that, thanks. The problem is efficiency being 6-8x slower than the same algorithm in Java...

Comment: Can it be that clojure uses arbitrary precision integers by default? If so, using fixed-width integers would probably give a good speedup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is dealing with the lazy seqs as an above answer mentioned. Here is my evidence....

```
;; original prime? function
(defn prime? [n]
  (or (= n 2) 
      (not (some #(zero? (rem n %)) 
                 (conj (range 3 
                              (inc (Math/sqrt n)) 
                              2) 
                       2)))))

;; prime? function using recur
(defn prime?-recur [num]
  (cond (< num 2) false
        (= num 2) true
        (zero? (mod num 2)) false
        :else (loop [n num
                     i 3]
                (cond (>= i (inc (Math/sqrt n))) true
                      (zero? (mod n i)) false
                      (< i (inc (Math/sqrt n))) (recur n (+ i 2))))))

;; original printPrimes with option for testing both prime? funs
;; note I changed this to start on 2 since 1 is not prime
(defn printPrimes [n fn] (take n (filter fn (iterate inc 2))))

;; printPrimes using recursion
(defn printPrimes-recur [num fn]
  (loop [n num i 2 primes []]
    (cond (and (fn i) (< (count primes) n)) (recur n (+ i 1) (conj primes i))
          (< (count primes) n) (recur n (+ i 1) primes)
          :else primes)))
```

Now, let's run these. First just to make sure the new code matches your original code:

```
foo> (= (printPrimes 10000 prime?)
        (printPrimes 10000 prime?-recur)
        (printPrimes-recur 10000 prime?)
        (printPrimes-recur 10000 prime?-recur))

true
```

And now for some times! (using your ExecTime function)

```
foo> (println (ExecTime printPrimes 10000 prime?)
              (ExecTime printPrimes 10000 prime?-recur)
              (ExecTime printPrimes-recur 10000 prime?)
              (ExecTime printPrimes-recur 10000 prime?-recur))



575.977 166.691 548.363 141.356
nil
```

So we see changing the prime? function to use recursion makes a pretty big difference (about 4x faster), and changing the printPrimes function to use recursion makes a difference too, but its just a tiny difference. I'm not sure how long the java version takes on my computer, but you can at least see from the times above that the loop/recur version seems faster than the original clojure version using the seqs.

Note: You could also try type hinting (http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints, http://kotka.de/blog/2012/06/Did_you_know_IX.html) to bring the speed up, but when I tried that, it didn't make a difference. That could be because I haven't done much of that before, so I could have been doing it improperly.

Comment: I edited my original question with a solution - same speed as Java with few simple changes.

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk nice find with the unchecked-remainder-int function.

Answer (score 3):

That method of timing this is so common it's built in

```
user> (time (reduce + (range 1000)))                                                                                                                                      
"Elapsed time: 1.350419 msecs"                                                                                                                                            
499500
```

Though to do it decently from a benchmarking perspective I recommend using Hugo Duncans's Criterium library and [reading this post on using it](http://hugoduncan.org/post/2010/benchmarking_clojure_code_with_criterium.xhtml). As for making clojure code run fast the clojure version is spending most of it's time allocating seq objects.

Comment: so it would be more efficient to use recur? I am using Clojure 1.4, would the newer version improve it? Thanks for your answer btw...

Answer (score 2):

Since you have early return in the Java code, I think the equivalent would be `some`, not `every`. For example:

```
(defn prime? [n]
  (or (= n 2)
      (and (odd? n)
           (not (some #(= 0 (mod n %)) 
                      (range 3 (inc (Math/sqrt n))))))))

(time (doall (filter prime? (range 10000))))
```

In my machine it's run roughly the same as your Java version.

Btw: I don't think 1 is considered a prime number though.

Comment: Sorry at start it looked promising, but I am checking for first 10000 primes, not for primes within first 10000 natural numbers. 10000 primes counts to check of over 104000 numbers, so in your case it would be (range 104000)... this still runs slightly faster, still around 400ms tho...

Comment: looking at [the source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/c6756a8bab137128c8119add29a25b0a88509900/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2414), `every?` seems to bail out early, at the first mismatch.

Comment: that makes sense too... still I have to figure out a way how to make it as efficient as the Java version...